# API's to use with java to have fun with

Tags: java

so I've been coding in java for the past 2 years, mainly making mods for Minecraft. Recently though I started making discord bots, and I've never really done anything with Java outside of Minecraft, and was using JDA(Java Discord API), and i realized how fun it was. I was wondering if any of you guys knew of some API's  i could use to do some cool stuff with :D

Comment: According to our [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) guidance, "**Some questions are still off-topic, even if they fit into one of the categories listed above:**...Questions asking us to *recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource* are off-topic..."

Answer (score 1):

If your looking to toy with some nice REST api's to interact with I could definitely suggest looking towards Amazon Web Services, or any of the Google API's such as Google Maps, or even Facebooks API.

Cheers and happy coding! :)